# Passive or Active

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Throughout history, with the developing of high technology, surgeries ______.

a. Have evolved 
b. Have been evolved

Which one is correct? I feel like the verb evolve cannot be transitive in this context so it should be active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say either!

Both sound fluent, so just use whichever sounds best in the context to you.

Examples:

Throughout history, with the developing of high technology, surgeries have evolved to be a common practice

Throughout history, with the developing of high technology, surgeries have been evolved in a way that makes them more effective

Comment: The second one should be "have been evolving".

Comment: I think it sounds alright either way; the whole point was the to get an example of passive voice